# When to choose React JS or Angular UI Framework

Tags: reactjs, angular

Recently I was going through React and Angular Comparison online (latest versions) & found both are good fit for Web Application UI.
While I was also wondering, there must be some differences which must be focused while deciding between two of them.

Lets suppose, I have one Java based web application with Spring MVC framework , Hibernate & JSF/JSP. Assuming this application is doing massive backend operations & displaying data on UI.

If in todays date, if I want to rebuild this type of application with latest Technology then how I should go for decision making out of React /Angular/other UI framework. For backend may be I will prefer to use Spring Boot which is advanced version of Spring MVC, but its really difficult to make choice on UI side.

Few points which I came across after googling are-

1. React is best when real time data update is required frequently.
2. React requires lot of Java script skills so it takes time develop web apps.
3. Now a days React is most preferred JS library which has more flexibility & big MNC's are also migrating from Angular to React.
4. While Angular has speedy development & also trying to improve on lacking points per release like Bundle Size, Performance etc.
5. Angular is preferred when web application is stable and not much enhancement are required.

Do we have some guidelines on when to use React / Angular?

Comment: This is mainly opinion based IMHO so it will be hard to get an answer. My advice is, pick one and run with it. They can both do the same job. Nowadays it usually comes down to personal preference as the libs are very mature.

Comment: IMHO it's more than just a matter of taste. I'd say 75% matter of taste, plus 25% of hard facts. Let's try to answer these 25%. However, I agree you can do everything with React you can do with Angular and vice versa. Both teams are watching and learning from each other.

Comment: Thanks @stephanrauh.  As mentioned above, in your opinion what would be the best  Technology to choose out of below-
**Current Stack** -> UI : JSF, Backend : Spring MVC + Hibernate, SOAP

**option** 1) UI: React , Backend : Spring Boot
**option** 2) UI Angular , Backend : Spring Boot

Need to take decision by - considering future stability, less development time & skills of resources who knows only JSF as of now. What would be better choice React or Angular?

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't encourage this kind of question. There's no point in encouraging flame wars. :) That's why I tried to focus on the hard facts instead of telling you me personal preference.

Comment: These types of questions are usually too broad for SO. Your best bet is to go on buildfaast.com or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time, both frameworks do the trick. Chose the framework that matches your team. If you like opinionated frameworks - i.e. frameworks that guide you - chose Angular. If you need a lot of freedom or if you don't like TypScript, chose React.

Small Angular applications have a surprisingly large memory footprint. So I'd prefer React for small things like Wordpress plugins. However, if you're writing a large application, memory and AFAIK even performance are in the same league.

Angular assumes it's owning the entire HTML page. So it's a bit difficult to embed Angular in an existing page, or to write microfrontends with Angular. But that's possible, too: just convert your Angular app into a webcomponent.

In any case, both frameworks are mature and have a huge community. The market share of React is larger, but if you're looking at the absolute download figures, both frameworks are popular and even growing. So @James is right, it's largely opinion based.

You gave some clues by mentioning the old application. If your team has a strong Java background, they'll probably prefer Angular. Modern React encourages to abandon object-oriented programming in favor of functional programming. That's pretty cool, but if you're a long-term JSF programmer (like 10+ years), you're already busy learning HTML, CSS, and TypeScript. Maybe it's a bit much to add a new programming paradigm to the stack of stuff to learn. But again - every team is different. Let your team decide!